# CPU usage spiking when SSL port is enabled on Jboss

Tags: java, ssl, jboss, jboss6.x

We are deploying an application on JBOSS. Initially we enabled only http port on Jboss and everything was proper. Initially we were doing the SSL offloading at the Load balancer and the traffic from load balancer to jboss was http. But due to compliance we had to encrypt the traffic between Jboss and load balancer. After enabling the SSL offloading at jboss side we are seeing spike in CPU usage. There is big difference. Any idea what may be happening?

Comment: Can you share the stacktrace from the corresponding Java thread which causes high CPU?